# Filter "all sites" section in stackexchange menu by typed input?

Tags: discussion, feature-request, stack-exchange-button

I'd love to see a feature in the *all sites* section of the *stackexchange menu* where the sites are filtered as you start typing (either with, or without an input field).

For instance, I like visiting Philosophy.SE a lot, but don't have much reputation for that site. So now, I constantly have to search for it in the menu, as it is randomly sorted.

I'd love a feature, where, when I start typing one or a few letters (i.g. <kbd>P</kbd>, <kbd>h</kbd>, etc.], it filters the sites by showing only the sites with that begin with these letters.

What do you think? Is it feasible?

Comment: I agree. This would be a great feature.

Comment: Same wish, that would be terribly cool

Answer (score 1):

I happen to have this very feature on the home page of [StackMobile](http://stackmobile.com).

Just click in the search box and start typing.

Answer (score 0):

Option 1: <kbd>Ctrl+F</kbd> <kbd>p</kbd><kbd>h</kbd>...

Option 2: There's a live search at the [SE Site Directory](https://stackexchange.com/sites).